# What is the reasoning behind the "await" keyword terminology?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

If you call a function synchronously the flow of the program still has to wait for the response so what is the difference here?

Comment: What language are we talking about? This may differ depending on context.

Comment: c# is the language.

Comment: See, the "flow of the program" is not necessarily identical to "the flow of the _thread_". By using an async function with await, you can do one of two things: 1. I/O based work or 2. CPU-based work. So, talking about the first: While waiting for an answer from the I/O counterpart, you free the _thread_ to do something else. Then, when the I/O is ready, the result is flagged to be ready to be picked up by _some thread_ which does not need to be the _same thread_ as before. That is: The flow of the instructions executed is the same. What changes is who and when executes and what get's blocked.

Comment: Right so the effect of using the await keyword is actually to free up another thread to access the function without having to wait for a response from the first call.

Comment: The whole point of asynchronity is that you actually don't have to wait for response, you are free to do other things in the meantime. But if that's the case then you need some operator to actually wait for the result.

Comment: await is *asyncronous wait*

Comment: Do you think the await keyword name is kind of counter intuitive because it means another call does not have to wait.

Comment: No matter what word is picked to express "continue here when the result is available, but in an asynchronous manner", no doubt someone can claim it's not clear enough. `async` was already taken for the other half. Expressing the complete semantics of an operation in a single unambiguous keyword is not always realistic.

Comment: BTW: Let me introduce you to Mr Stephen Cleary : https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming whose blogs on and about the topic is always worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you have a few tasks that needs to be done. A and B, each consisting of several steps, A1, A2, B1, B2, and so on. A and B are independent, the steps for each tasks needs to be run in order.

So a typical way to execute the tasks would be `A1, A2, B1, B2` or `B1, B2, A1, A2`. If the tasks are mostly CPU bound this works fine. But if A1 is an IO-operation we would be wasting CPU time if that was scheduled first. So in that case it would be better to run things in the order `A1, B1, A2, B2`. On modern computers IO operations can be many order of magnitude slower than CPU instructions, so freeing the CPU to do other stuff can be a major win, especially when trying to write a responsive UI.

But now we have made our program much more complicated to write and reason about, the 'program order' no longer matches the execution order.

The classical way to do this was with callbacks, and it could look something like:

```
public void A(){
    A1(A2, A1FailureHandler);
}
public void A1(Action<A1Result> callback, Action<Exception> failCallback){
   ...
}
public void A2(A1Result r){ ... }
public void A1FailureHandler(Exception ex){ ... }
```

This tend to make the code much more complicated to write and understand, especially if your tasks consist of many more steps. The solution is to let the compiler worry about it! When the async keyword is used it lets us write the above code using a more familiar structure

```
public async void A(){
    try{
        var a1Result = await A1();
        A2(a1Result);
    }
    catch(Exception e){...}
}
public Task A1(){...}
public void A2(A1Result r){...}
```

Behind the scene the method will be rewritten as a class, all local variables changed to fields, and the A-method changed to a large switch-statement that keeps track on which step it is currently running. This lets us write things in the logical program order, and let the compiler and runtime worry about the actual execution order. However, abstractions tend to be leaky, and asynchronous programs can be more difficult to understand and debug.

Answer (score 0):

From the await operator language [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await).

> The `await` operator suspends evaluation of the enclosing [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)
> method until the asynchronous operation represented by its operand
> completes. When the asynchronous operation completes, the `await`
> operator returns the result of the operation, if any. When the await
> operator is applied to the operand that represents an already
> completed operation, it returns the result of the operation
> immediately without suspension of the enclosing method. The `await`
> operator doesn't block the thread that evaluates the async method.
> When the await operator suspends the enclosing async method, the
> control returns to the caller of the method.

So the `await` keyword means that the instructions below will wait for the completion of the previous async instruction. Without the await keyword, execution order will not be guaranteed and subsequent instructions will probably be executed before the async task termination.